# Remote Images in a ListView with ViewHolder pattern

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Main question:

What is the most efficient bug free method of lazy loading remote images in a simple ListView adapter that utilizes the ViewHolder pattern?

I currently have an implementation that will first check a SoftReference Bitmap HashMap for a  soft caches version of the image. If that fails I check my hard cache for a copy of the image. If that fails I get it from the web. I do all of this on a separate thread and in a queue to eliminate concurrent or duplicate downloads.

The problem is when loading through a callback. Because I utilize the ViewHolder pattern my views are constantly being recycled and I have not found a solid way to eliminate different images being randomly attached to my ImageViews. I do default to a default image before each load but because the views are being recycled so quickly "old" listeners apply onto my ImageView providing the wrong image which are then replaced with the correct image.

The only semi-solid solution I have found is to use the ViewHolder itself as the listener but this only makes the problem less apparent. It still happens on a fast scroll.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime

Comment: This has been annoying problem for me as well and sometimes forcing me not to use recycle mechanism (performance in exchange for better user experience of not seeing swapped image). Would appreciate if you post your own answer if you crack this problem and you will get +1 from me :) I'll post something up too if I find anything

Comment: I see the same sh*tty behavior. Another area in Android, where the system itself does not help, but forces every user to re-implement the solution from scratch. Most fail on iterations 1-5. And yes I am sort of Android fanboy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution to the image switching problem and I will provide a code chunk below. I will not accept it yet though because I do not know if this is the most efficient method which is my original question. If this is implemented correctly it will work perfectly.

```
 public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     ViewHolder holder;
     if (convertView == null) {

     ...

     String imagePath = insertImageUrlHere();
     Object tag = holder.userThumb.getTag();
     if (tag != null && tag.equals(imagePath)) {
          // Do nothing
     } else {
          holder.userThumb.setTag(imagePath);
          holder.userThumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
          AsynchronousImageLoadingUtility.load(imagePath, holder);
     }

     ...

     return convertView;
 }

 private static class ViewHolder implements AsynchronousImageLoadingUtilityCallback {

     private ImageView userThumb;

     @Override
     public void onImageLoad(String source, Bitmap image) {
          if (image != null && userThumb.getTag().equals(source)) {
               userThumb.setImageBitmap(image);
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes it does. I have since the time of this post built out the pattern into a much better utility here: https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime

Comment: @HandlerExploit Can you paste your code here as in above code doesnt complete the `if (convertView == null)`

Comment: can you please look over this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994233/imageview-overlap-when-adding-more-items-in-existing-listview

Comment: Great solution, Is fine to me too.